# How to start/stop a python script as a service at a specific time on CentOS?

Tags: centos, systemd, python, services, scheduling

I am trying to put a python script on a VPS running CentOS 7, that crawls some stock data online from a web service. What I want to do is to set this script as an OS service that start/stops at a specific time.

How can I do it?

EDIT:this is the result of `systemctl status python-script`

```
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/python-script.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-05-16 01:11:50 +0430; 15h ago
 Main PID: 854 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 16 01:11:43 boiga.server1.more.com systemd[1]: Started Python Script Serv...
May 16 01:11:50 boiga.server1.more.com python3[854]: Traceback (most recent c...
May 16 01:11:50 boiga.server1.more.com python3[854]: File "/root/script.py", ...
May 16 01:11:50 boiga.server1.more.com python3[854]: await (websocketConnect())
May 16 01:11:50 boiga.server1.more.com python3[854]: NameError: name 'await' ...
May 16 01:11:50 boiga.server1.more.com systemd[1]: python-script.service: mai...
May 16 01:11:50 boiga.server1.more.com systemd[1]: Unit python-script.service...
May 16 01:11:50 boiga.server1.more.com systemd[1]: python-script.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a service that runs this python script by creating a service file `/etc/systemd/system/python-script.service` , like this example :

```
[Unit]
Description=Python Script Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /root/script.py
Restart=on-abort


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then run `systemctl daemon-reload` to reload systemd and `systemctl enable python-script` to enable the service.

Running the service should give you something like this:

```
systemctl status python-script
● python-script.service - Python Script Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/python-script.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2020-05-13 23:10:30 CEST; 2s ago
  Process: 27405 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /root/script.py (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 27405 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 13 23:10:30 server1 systemd[1]: Started Python Script Service.
May 13 23:10:30 server1 python3[27405]: Hello World!
```

Regarding planning the start/stop of the service, you can use crontab for that

Comment: Hi anisk, thank you for help. Can you more explain about `crontab`  and how to use it?

Comment: @user3486308, You can use crontab -e  to edit crontabs and add two crons if you want, one that starts the service and another that stops it, a simple example is the following : 00 8 * * * systemctl start python-script 2&1 >/dev/null
15 18 * * * systemctl stop python-script 2&1 >/dev/null

Comment: When I run `systemctl enable python-script ` it shows nothing!

Comment: what it the name of the file that you've created in /etc/systemd/system/ and what is the output of systemctl status python-script ?

Comment: I chose the exact name as you suggested and added the result to my question. Please read the edit part.

Comment: Obviously now you have a service recognized by systemd. The log is truncated, but shows an error in you application on python level ( NameError: name 'await' ). Have you tested separately the command /usr/bin/python3 /root/script.py?